# Odoo inheritance button

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to add new  button to project.task model but i definitely have something mixed up here, can you guys help me with that and explain what's wrong  with my logic. i bet there is problem not only in method. maybe i need to add a field in my class called "`message_follower_ids" ?

```
class ProjectTaskFollowers(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.task.followers'
    _inherit = 'project.task'


@api.multi
def parameters_transfer(self):
    self.message_follower_ids = project_id.message_follower_ids




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>


<record id="act_project_task_inherited" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">taks.project.fallowers.inh.act</field>
        <field name="res_model">project.task.followers</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form,calendar,pivot,graph</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
        </field>
    </record>


<!-- Inherit Form View to Modify it -->
<record id="view_form_project_task_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">task.project.fallowers.inher</field>
    <field name="model">project.task.followers</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <xpath expr="//div[@name='button_box']" postition='inside'>
       <button class="oe_link" type="action" name="%(act_project_task_inherited)%">
           <field string="Assign Project Followers" name="project_id.message_follower_ids" widget="statinfo"/>
       </button>
       </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes

    self.message_follower_ids = project_id.message_follower_ids
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: You need indentation for code inside `for` block

Comment: ok i just removed for so now it's          @api.multi
def parameters_transfer(self):
    for taks in self:
    self.message_follower_ids = project_id.message_follower_ids , there is no errors but button doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a button on `project.task`, because you're extending `project.task.followers` here.

Comment: well i need to add Assign Project Followers button to project.task form view , with method that looks something like this @api.multi
def parameters_transfer(self):
    self.message_follower_ids = project_id.message_follower_ids
That was i told.

Comment: OK, i will edit my answer again. You will need to extend `project.task` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent your python code correctly, and i don't know if your code is working well. You also have to extend `project.task` the right way. Your code is creating a completly new model `project.task.followers`. I will provide another way to add followers (i changed the method name!):

```py
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    _inherit = "project.task"
    _name = "project.task"  # optional

    @api.multi
    def add_project_followers(self):
        for task in self:
            partner_ids = task.project_id.message_follower_ids.ids
            task.message_subscribe(partner_ids)
```

EDIT: if you want to use a method for a button, you have to use `type="object"` and set the method name into `name`. You also have to use the correct model:

```xml
<record id="view_form_project_task_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">task.project.fallowers.inher</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[@name='button_box']" postition='inside'>
            <button string="Add Followers" type="object" name="add_project_followers" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes. trying to figure it out all day.. and result is the same.

Comment: AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 5 any suggestons?

Comment: and if i coment out my action i getting this                Field `project_id.message_follower_ids` does not exist

Comment: Yes, the action isn't needed. Try it out with a normal button. You can't use dot notation in fields. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: one more question do i need one2many field in my class or it should work without it?

Comment: damn.. i maybe such stupid mistake early in the morning and because of that it took me so long. , thanx, you are the man